# Keycloak server OTP setting to be restored during upgrade

Tags: keycloak

I have a keycloak server for user authentication. The server is federated with LDAP backend. 2FA is also enabled on the server. When the user logs in with its credential an OTP screen pops up, If the user is new it has to scan the QR code via authenticator app (freeOTP), once the registration is completed; Any subsquent login the user will have to just enter the code generated on the authenticator app.

The problem appears when the keycloak realm is recreated during the upgrade, the OTP setting vanishes and the user will have to scan the QR code again to enable the 2FA.

OTP related settings are as below.

```
      "otpPolicyType": "totp",
      "otpPolicyInitialCounter": 0,
      "otpPolicyLookAheadWindow": 1,
      "otpSupportedApplications": [
        "FreeOTP"
      ],
      "requiredActions": [{
          "alias": "CONFIGURE_TOTP",
          "name": "Configure OTP",
          "providerId": "CONFIGURE_TOTP",
          "enabled": true,
          "defaultAction": true,
          "priority": 10,
          "config": {}
        }
      ],
```

Can someone help to understand if the OTP related settings for the existing users can be restored after the upgrade?